# Enforcing types in Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a interface for typing that looks like the following

```
interface Bob{
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}
```

However, I don't really want number as any number can be valid. How can I enforce the type of Bob to be numbers strictly in a JSON file like the following.

```
{
  "None": -1,
  "foo": 22,
  "moo": 55,
  "raar": 13,
  "zaar": 2,
  "bar": 0,
  "fooboo": 22,
  "mooboo": 1000,
}
```

That JSON contains around 200 entries hence doing a manual typedef is not optimal.

What I aim to achieve

```
const myvar: Bob;
myvar.a = 2222 // this should throw an error as this number is not defined in the JSON
myvar.b = -1 //this is ok as it is in the JSON
```

Thanks!

Comment: Import json (it will be typed), then do `type values = typeof v[keyof typeof v];` (where `v` is your imported json)

Comment: wont work. You still can user other numbers -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MDeAoGMBEA5cAUxwC4YBaARgBotcAzEEUmAJlduxwFsmWBWfp1wAnAIZiRLSgGZhOAF4SpZDnRwAjSSwAM8xiA19Varr0PGYlHTdoBfDBigBPAA6EYAEgBqYgDYAroQQADwAKjCEAB5QhGAAJhAwhnCEwFAAfCgwYQDaANaEziD0OQC6ANxObh4QAa6uICKx8XgB3BqEIkmoLu4l8IhgBUUDfYQDCOCVjgCWYLEi9GLAHgBChpjY2GJkdQ1NLW0dXRBV2zAae-WNzYSt7Z3d59vA1wd3DyfPGA4YoJBYHhZqsNlcYGDslsYLsYDIAJw6eHCcEySiIhHCN5WVgyX5VDBAA

Comment: @MartinGodzina will work, if you type it `as const` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MDeAoGMBEA5cAUxwC4YBaARgBotcAzEEUmAJlduxwFsmWBWfp1wAnAIZiRLSgGZhOAF4SpZDnRwAjSSwAM8xiA19Varr0PGYlHTdoBfGGIgxQkKAG4MGKAE8ADoQwACQAamIANgCuhBAAPAAqMIQAHlCEYAAmzoZwhMBQAHwoMPEA2gDWhD4g9CUAup6+ATAQkX5+ICJpGXiR3BqEIs6oTYQ18IhgFVXjo+MI4A1eAJZgaSL0YsCBAEKGmNjYYmSt7Z3dvf2DEJ6HMBonbR1dhD19A0O3h8CPZy9vV0+GDsXlc0BgeGW2z2DxgMOKB0cZBkAE4dCjhLCZJQ0ajhD8rKwZMDPBggA

Comment: Thank you @zerkms! Works like a charm. Do you mind explaining what does the `as const` do at the end?

Comment: @DingMa https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Comment: Wow didn't know all of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @zerkms for the answer.

```
const json = {
  "None": -1,
  "foo": 22,
  "moo": 55,
  "raar": 13,
  "zaar": 2,
  "bar": 0,
  "fooboo": 22,
  "mooboo": 1000,
} as const;

type $Values<T extends object> = T[keyof T];
type supportedNumbers = typeof json[keyof typeof json];

interface Bob{
    a: supportedNumbers;
    b: supportedNumbers;
    c: supportedNumbers;
}

const NiceBob: Bob = {
  a: 3909, //error
  b: 319039, //error
  c: -1 //no error
};
```

Example can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MDeAoGMBEA5cAUxwC4YBaARgBotcAzEEUmAJlduxwFsmWBWfp1wAnAIZiRLSgGZhOAF4SpZDnRwAjSSwAM8xiA19Varr0PGYlHTdoBfGGIgxQkKAG4MGKAE8ADoQwACQAamIANgCuhBAAPAAqMIQAHlCEYAAmzoZwhMBQAHwoMPEA2gDWhD4g9CUAup6+ATAQkX5+ICJpGXiR3BqEIs6oTYQ18IhgFVXjo+MI4A1eAJZgaSL0YsCBAEKGmNjYYmSt7Z3dvf2DEJ6HMBonbR1dhD19A0O3h8CPZy9vV0+GDsXlc0BgeGW2z2DxgMOKB0cZBkAE4dCjhLCZJQ0ajhD8KJRgZ4MEA)

Docs can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

Comment: Do you need to refer to the `const json` at runtime? Or do you only define it to define the type `supportedNumbers`? If it is the latter: You could go without having a const by using `type json = { ... }` and `type supportedNumbers = json[keyof json]`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAVgzgewHZQLxQN4Cgq6gQwBtCEB3CAEwEYAuKKnPIk8igJjoCJEBbCAZWAAnAJZIA5pywBfLFgD08qEIiJCAN1VRgCKAAMqUAD5RuCPoNETOerKEhQ4AVzBgEQ4JQAq4LenjIANoA1hAgCABmsIhIALpy9tAAGmiYjLj4dM6u7p4UPpBw6VAARlkubh7evkXSQA

Comment: in my case `const ` is good since it is loaded when the app is running and will not be modified